# Adding time to a running slurm job

Tags: slurm

I have a job running a linux machine managed by slurm.
Now that the job is running for a few hours I realize that I underestimated the time required for it to finish and thus the value of the `--time` argument I specified is not enough. Is there a way to add time to an existing running job through slurm?

Comment: How did you used `--time` on `sbatch`? like this? `sbatch run.sh --time=0-00:00:01`

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Use the scontrol command to modify a job

`scontrol update jobid=<job_id> TimeLimit=<new_timelimit>`

Use the SLURM time format, eg. for 8 days 15 hours: `TimeLimit=8-15:00:00`

Requires admin privileges, on some machines.

Will be allowed to users only if the job is not running yet, on most machines.

Comment: only the admin can do it

Comment: should time limit be on seconds? @Carles Fenoy

Comment: @Avatar time limit has to be in slurm time format specification (eg. for 8 days 15 hours use timelimit=8-15:00:00

Comment: @MedhatHelmy I disagree - just tried this on the system where I don't have admin rights and worked without a hitch.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: 

    $ scontrol update jobid=1284608 TimeLimit=00:04:00
    Access/permission denied for job 1284608
    
    $ sbatch --version
    slurm 17.02.10

Comment: On most systems this will only work if the job is not running yet. If it is running, you need admin permissions (otherwise users could "cheat the system" too easily by submitting short jobs and then blowing up the available time when they start running).

Comment: Does the new_timelimit start now, or when the job was first submitted?

Comment: on our system it does not even work if the job is not yet running, if you are not an admin

Comment: Is this adding to the wall time or setting a new wall time?

Comment: @zyy this is setting a new wall time

Answer (score 14):

To build on the example provided above, you can also use "+" and "-" to increment / decrement the `TimeLimit`.

From the [scontrol man page][https://slurm.schedmd.com/scontrol.html]:

> either specify a new time limit value or precede the time and equal sign with a "+" or "-" to increment or decrement the current time limit (e.g. "TimeLimit+=30")

We regularly get requests like "I need 3 more hours for job XXXXX to finish!!!", which would translate to:

```
scontrol update job=XXXXX TimeLimit=+03:00:00
```

Comment: The astute reader might note that the manual actually states _precede the time **and equal** sign with a "+" or "-"_, but your example puts the + after the =. However, I can confirm that either order seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't specified a walltime in your Slurm job script, Slurm will typically use the default walltime specified in your Slurm cluster configuration. To increase the walltime of a running job in Slurm, you can use the scontrol command to modify the job's time limit. Here's the command you can use:

**scontrol update JobID=<job_id> TimeLimit=<new_walltime>**

Replace <job_id> with the actual job ID of the job you want to modify, and <new_walltime> with the new walltime you want to set for the job. Make sure you have the necessary permissions to modify the job, as this may require administrative privileges or job ownership.

eg:
**scontrol update JobID=12345 TimeLimit=2-00:00:00**

This example increases the walltime of the job with ID 12345 to 2 days.